# Filenet Query and sub query for check other documents

Tags: filenet-p8, filenet-content-engine, filenet, filenet-process-engine, filenet-cpe

so basically, i want to get document if only other document is not exists. i try many ways and still not found the correct way. the last query i tried is this query.

is it possible to do it in single filenet query? in my current situation, it is not possible to use program/code to do 2 step. that why i try to use single query.

```
Select TOP 1 * from Document where MimeType = 'application/pdf' and ((Select count(*) from Document d2 where  id_card= '${DF:1}' and doc_id_card = '112' and d2.This INFOLDER '/EE/${DF:1}') = 0) and id_card= '${DF:1}' and doc_id_card = '113' and Document.This INFOLDER '/EE/${DF:1}'
```